# AngularJS Webapplication meets Wordpress Blog

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, integration

We are developing a **hybrid Mobile Application**, which will be also reachable via web.

Stack:

DB: NO-SQL / Firebase
Server: Firebase/ Node.js
Client Mobile: Cordova, Ionic, AngularJS
Web: AngularJS

For **SEO reasons** and to **deliver our content** we are using **Wordpress** as CMS Engine.

**We want to connect our Webapplication and integrate it seamless into our Wordpress blog.**

The idea is to have a structure like this.

```
-Main Application(kind of Landingpage AngularJS/Application)
- Blogcategorie1 (WP)
- Blogcategorie2 (WP)
- Blogcategorie3 (WP)
- About Us (WP)
- Authors (WP)
- Impressum (WP)
```

**1) How can this be done?**

**2) Are there any performance issues integrating Webapplications into Wordpress Engine?**

**3) Other ideas to integrate Wordpress and AngularJS seamless?**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are more solutions you your needs one of them is to use an angularjs enabled theme, you can do this usign this plugin: [AngularJS for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/angularjs-for-wp/) this will help you add angularjs to your theme so from that point on all you have to do is to build your app in a template file.

Would having the 2 things apart be a solution? run your wordpress independently of your angular webapplication. What do they have in common except running on the same server? should they be in the same folder? I don't see an issue in this case either.

If things get complicated and both above ideas are no go's then have a look at [wp-api](https://github.com/royboy789/WP-API) you can get wordpress data using wordpress api but this might fall out of your scope of using wordpress.

Comment: Thanx alex.

Both AngularJS and Wordpress will be part of a kind of Marketplace solution. We want to use Wordpress for delivering the static contents and AngularJS for the real Application. They do not really interact, should just appear seamless especially in terms of UI and CI.

Comment: In this case I wouldn't complicate myself with anything, just design the 2 of them so they appear the same, add links between them and that is it. :)

Comment: Would be great to use the style and the responsive design capabilities from the wordpress engine. do you think this could make problems?

Comment: wordpress style and responsive design depends on you worpdress active theme design so the theme has css files and js files that produces the layout (and html of course but that is another thing) and the css and js usually are in separate public files so you can link the style.css file from your theme that you have in wordpress in your angularJS app and use it's css, same goes for javascript and from that point on if you use the same rules you'll have similar style and responsiveness.